# How to refer to an object using user input?

Tags: python, performance, class, oop, object

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

redcar = Car("red")
bluecar = Car("blue")
yellowcar = Car("yellow")
greencar = Car("green")

choice = input("color? :")
```

This an sample code here, I know it is not practical but it's just to give an example of the issue I'm having assuming that the user inputs a choice of 'redcar','bluecar','yellowcar','greencar'. How can I store the corresponding object into the variable choice instead of it being a string? I understand that I can create a dictionary like `mainDict = {'redcar':redcar,'bluecar':bluecar,'yellowcar':yellowcar,'greencar':greencar}` and then refer the user input with the dictionary to return the corresponding object but I don't wish to do this for an 100 object or even 1000 is there a more efficient method?

Comment: "I can create a dictionary" - this is the correct way of solving this. In fact, Python's namespaces are dictionaries, so you'll end up using a dictionary anyway

Comment: do not prepare 16 million colors of cars. Ask for a color, create that car. done - I want to have one thats a "yellowish green with tinted windows of a somewhat puprlish-blue hue with perlessant glimmer particles only on the door parts". thank you